# While loop code keeps running

Tags: python, list, while-loop

For some reason this code doesn't print anything and doesn't stop running, can anybody tell me what is going wrong here?

```
l = [1,2]
i = 0
k = l[i]+l[i+1]
while k <= 10:
    l.append(k)
    i += 1

print l
```

Comment: You don't modify `k` in the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `k` (and therefore the loop condition) is set before the loop using the current value of `i` (0), and never changes during the loop execution. You would have to reassign `k` based on the new value for `i` inside the loop for it to change.

Answer (score 3):

Python evaluates the value of `k` so that `k` isn't the expression, but the *result* of that expression:

```
k = l[i]+l[i+1]   # In your case it's l[0] + l[1] = 3
```

You probably want to evaluate `k` every loop:

```
l = [1,2]
i = 0

for i in range(0, 10 + 1):
  l.append(l[i] + l[i + 1])

print l
```

And just for fun, a more Pythonic Fibonacci sequence generator (literally):

```
def Fibonacci():
  a, b = 0, 1

  while True:
    yield a

    a += b
    a, b = b, a

for n in Fibonacci():
  raw_input(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move the line with k in it:

```
l = [1,2]
i = 0
k = l[i]+l[i+1]
while k <= 10:
    l.append(k)
    i += 1
    k = l[i]+l[i+1]

print l
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing any changes to the k variable. Once you calculate the value of K, the code gets stock in the while loop because the value of k never changes, you simply keep appending the value of k to the list.

Answer (score -1):

not sure about python,
but looks like you update the value of K ever also, not sure what is the scope of the while loop in python syntax.